# Yii using ActiveRecord

Tags: php, yii2

In my Yii application I have the model:

```
class Article extends ActiveRecord
{
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{article}}';
}


public static function getLatestArticles()
{
    return parent::find()->where( 'TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(published) <= 7 
                        AND ISNULL(arch)')
                       ->orderBy(
                           ['DAYOFWEEK(published)' => SORT_DESC,
                            'rubric' => SORT_ASC,
                           ])->all();
}

public function getArticlerubric()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Rubric::class,['id' => 'rubric']);
}
```

What is the correct way to use the getLatestArticles() function : parent::find(), self::find()  or static::find() ?

Comment: What do you mean by "right way"? Are you aware of the different meanings? Do they matter in your context?

Comment: Yes, I understand different meanings of parent, self and static. Moreover I have tried all of them and all variants are working. So I'm confused which variant to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static::find() would probably be the best bet, but self::find() should do the job.

Otherwise it's Article::find()